# SQL 2005 change IP address and subnet

Tags: sql-server-2005, migration, disaster-recovery, database-administration

I have to move few sql servers to a new subnet ( change IP address and mask only ), need to know what should be best practice or correct way of doing this? the sql servers are not in cluster.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Shut down SQL Server service prior to changing the IP addresses
- Change the addresses on the machines
- Make sure the IP addresses that SQL is binding to match your new ones.  In SQL Server Configuration Manager choose Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (or whatever your instance names are) and verify the addresses on the IP Addresses tab
- Start SQL Server

That should be all you need for the database engine.

A couple of other points:

- Obviously make sure your name resolution gets updated appropriately (DNS, hosts, etc).
- If you have any apps that hit the databases that don't connect after the change when others do check the connection strings and/or ODBC data sources to see if you're using hard coded IP addresses.  Same goes with server aliases, check the connection strings on those (also in Configuration Manager, under SQL Native Client Configuration)